# writeToSequence does not work properly in TIFFImageWriter class

Tags: java, javax.imageio

My primary intention is to merge multiple different tiff image files into one single file. I have a working code that uses *TwelveMonkeys* library. Now I want to use the default java library to achieve the same goal. I prepared a small code example to debug and find the problem.

```
  public static ByteArrayOutputStream mergeIntoSingle(List<String> imagePaths) {
    ImageWriter imageWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff").next();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;

    try {
       byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ImageOutputStream outputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
      imageWriter.setOutput(outputStream);
      imageWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);

      for (String path : imagePaths) {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(path));
        ImageWriteParam writeParams = imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
        IIOMetadata metadata = imageWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(new ImageTypeSpecifier(image),
            writeParams);

        IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(image, null, metadata);
        imageWriter.writeToSequence(iioImage, null);
      }
      imageWriter.endWriteSequence();
      byteArrayOutputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return byteArrayOutputStream;
  }
```

I debug the code and *BufferedImage* and *IIOImage* variables are not null. But *endWriteSequence* method does not write the content of image to the *ImageOutputStream*. Therefore, *ImageOutputStream* and *ByteArrayOutputStream* variables are being empty. I went through related questions and [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#writeToSequence(javax.imageio.IIOImage,javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam)), but could not find any useful information about it.

Comment: I think your code looks reasonable, but I don't understand the `byteArrayOutputStream.close()` line. I think you should instead use `outputStream .flush()` or `outputStream close()` in case the stream implementation does some internal buffering. I don't get the part about the *"variables are being null"* as the variables you mention can't be `null` without causing exceptions earlier on...

Comment: More precisely *mergeIntoSingle* method returns null.

Comment: But how can that happen? You explicitly assign the variable you return using `byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()`... That can't ever be `null` unless you get an `OutOfMemoryError` or a similar exotic case.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I meant it returns empty.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my initial comment, there is a small problem with the code, in that you don't properly flush/close the `outputStream` (the `ImageOutputStream` that wraps the `byteArrayOutputStream`). Instead you only close the `ByteArrayOutputStream` (which is a no-op). That means that if the stream implementation does internal caching/buffering, it will never be flushed to the underlying stream. In my very limited testing, I could reproduce the problem and this does indeed seem to be the case.

A safer and more idiomatic Java 7+ version of the code would create the wrapped steam using try-with-resources, and fix the problem (by automatically invoking `close()`):

```java
public static ByteArrayOutputStream mergeIntoSingle(List<String> imagePaths) {
    ImageWriter imageWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff").next();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (ImageOutputStream outputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {
        imageWriter.setOutput(outputStream);
        imageWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);

        for (String path : imagePaths) {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(path));
            ImageWriteParam writeParams = imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
            IIOMetadata metadata = imageWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(new ImageTypeSpecifier(image),
                                                                       writeParams);

            IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(image, null, metadata);
            imageWriter.writeToSequence(iioImage, null);
        }
        imageWriter.endWriteSequence();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return byteArrayOutputStream;
}
```

PS: I think the `TIFFImageWriter` *should* have invoked `flush()` on the stream in the `endWriteSequence()` method (that's what TwelveMonkeys library does). However, you should always make sure you close any stream you open, so the above code is better in any case.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. The issue was related to, as you mentioned,  *flush/close* operations. Using try with resource handles them on behalf of me.